# Setting the external proxy which requires authentication for Postman

Tags: postman

I am setting up the native windows Postman and trying to run the "Request Header" api provided in Postman Echo collection. I get the following error.

"Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407"

I can see in the postman console that it is picking up the correct proxy server from environment. My proxy server requires authentication, how do I provide credential information. I tried to start Postman using the following command but it did not help.

postman.exe --proxy-server=userName:password@myproxy:8090

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the proxy tab in Settings does not allow authenticated proxies.
Entering proxy info in the format "userName:password@myproxy" will cause everything before the '@' symbol to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You may already know, but since version 5.2, Postman includes a "Proxy" tab into the "Settings" section.

You should be able to configure your proxy on your system (if you are using Windows you can do it in Internet Options>>Connections>>LAN Settings) and then enable the "Use system proxy" in this tab.

Answer (score 1):

After testing this method is helpful：
Windows-  create a postman.bat file with the following content:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://USER:PASS@host:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://USER:PASS@host:port
start C:\path\to\Postman.exe
```

as I get this from [here](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-)

Answer (score 0):

In the "Global Proxy Configuration" section of the Proxy tab, setting the "Proxy Server" value to - 
userName:password@proxyHost:proxyPort resolves the issue.

Comment: As soon as you click away from the text box it clears the username:password part.

Comment: Not including the domain in the username i.e. domainName\userName seems to result in the text box getting cleared. Try prefixing the username with "domainName\"

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem for Postman and also for other local tools that are not capable of NTLM authentication against a proxy.

The solution is the open source proxy service/demon CNTLM that runs under Linux, macOS and Windows. The project has not been updated for a while but I could easily install and run it under Windows 10.

Best part is that it is able to check your proxy's capabilities and automatically find the latest NTLM version that the proxy supports.

http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Proxy-Authorization` header with value `Basic base64encode($user:$password)`

Answer (score 0):

launch postman through :

```
vagrant@localhost:~/Downloads/Postman-linux-x64-7.6.0/Postman/app$ ./Postman
```

and set/unset proxy values